# How to define a proper selector to invoke a jquery function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two accordions (two forms) in a page which are working independently (two Ajax calls). The user can change something in one of them and save it. I am going to restrict the users so whenever they change something in one of those forms they have to save them before making any changes in the other form. (They should not be able to make changes in both without saving). 
I use the following JS code:

> ```
> $('#accordion1 *').click(function(event){
>     if(model.dataChangedInAccordion2){
>         // warning modal pops up
>     }
> });
> $('#accordion2 *').click(function(event){
>     if(model.dataChangedInAccordion1){
>         // warning modal pops up
>     }
> });
> ```

but the click function does not work. Can anybody tell me what is the problem? How would be the selectors? (there are a lot of elements in each accordion)

Comment: Can you please post a minimal example of your HTML DOM you are trying to use the selectors on?

Comment: you dont need to add '*' character. The propagation of click event will trigger the `$('#accordion')` click whenever you click in a child element of the accordion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if the user make modifications in one accordion but decides not to save them and modify the other one instead ? I think you should make these accordion readonly or non-editable. Then add a button for each accordion 'edit'. This way you can control that the user is only modifying one accordion at a time. That is for the UI part

Also, as I said in the comments, you dont need to add '*' character. The propagation of click event will trigger the `$('#accordion')` click whenever you click in a child element of the accordion. That is for the Jquery part.

-demo here https://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/ce81oLwz/

Comment: I will provide two options in the model "save changes" and "not Save" so that the user can proceed. I also have tried different types of selectors none of them work. I mean the click function does not work.

Comment: The two accordions cunstructed using jquery accordion. Do you think is it a problem for that click event?

Comment: yes ! You must insure that the `#accordion` elements already exist in the DOM when you attach the event listener. Else, you are attaching the listener on nothing. The other solution is to attach a global listener to the document with `.on()`. `$('document').on('click', '#accordion1', function(){ ... });`

Comment: Actually #accordion exists when I debug the code in firebug. However I tried the $('document').on('click', '#accordion1', function(){ ... }) but it still cannot invoke the click event!

Comment: Yes, the accordion exists, but, does it exist when the code is parsed ? Can you provide a jsfiddle or something ? what is the content of your `click` function ?

Comment: thanks a lot. I jsut put the function after the accordion function is done and now it is working.